# Fetching a value on Gatsby build and exposing it to each component

Tags: gatsby

i have gatsby application,

i wanna fetch a api (let say aws apigateway) to get some UI config, then assign the config value globally in the application when i build the application

therefore, each of the small component (not page) can read the value, to dynamic display something or do something base on the config

but i dont want the application fetch the api at run time, can gatsby do it? since i cant find any example

Pass config value when createPage is not fit for my situration, as i said **"each of the small component (not page) can read the value"**

Answer (score 0):

The standard mechanism for components fetch data in Gatsby is by requesting it from source plugins using Graph QL.

Most likely you can find an existing source plugin that will work with your API, for example [gatsby-source-apiserver](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-apiserver/?=gatsby-source).

If none of the existing source plugins work for your needs, you can write a new source plugin for your data. See the [tutorial on writing source plugins](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/source-plugin-tutorial/)